# Extend class without its decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

Class I'd like to stub in test

```
@stubOnTest('CategorizationServiceStub')
class CategorizationService {
 ...
```

The stub class

```
import CategorizationService from '../../server/services/CategorizationService';

export default class CategorizationServiceStub extends CategorizationService {
 ....
```

The decorator to 'catch' the calls to `CategorizationService` and replace it with mock

```
export default function stubOnTest(stubbedClassStr: string) {
  const pathToStubbedClass = path.resolve(__dirname, stubsDir, stubbedClassStr);
  const stubbedClass = require(pathToStubbedClass);
  ...
```

But when `CategorizationServiceStub` is called, it extends `CategorizationService` which calls decorator `@stubOnTest('CategorizationServiceStub')`.

And then it becomes an endless loop.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Have `stubOnTest` check that the class it is stubbing is not already stubbed. Maybe add a property to subbed classes like `stubbed = true` that doesn't exist on the base class.

Comment: Just an observation but decorating a class so that it can be tested or stubbed to test another system seems like a problematic design.

Comment: put `const stubbedClass = require(pathToStubbedClass);` and every subsequent task in `stubOnTest` inside a `Promise.resolve().then(...)` or `process.nextTick(...)` so that it is executed **after the module has exported** its members. This should break the cycle

Comment: I'd recommend to make *CategorizationServiceStub.ts* export a function that is called with the original class by the decorator and does return the stub class. It should not `import` the `CategorizationService` (which causes a circular reference)

Comment: Just some context: I'd like to globally mock some services being testing with Cypress. That service is called in other services, controllers, etc. Not one place. I'm trying to find a way to 'globally' mock it. I.E. If in NODE_ENV test it will use the mocked version. Something like Rails does ala carrier_wave (writes to disk in test, uses S3 in prod).